# Prolog counting max distance of not negative sum in 2 lists

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

what i want to find is the maximum J-I (in terms of arrays) where the element of the first list is bigger than the element of the second list and get that max difference. 
My problem is that i cannot count in which element i am currently so i cannot get the maximum distance .
This is how far I've gone :

```
computedistance([Hd1|Tl1],[Hd2|Tl2],I,J,Dist) :- 
       Hd1 =< Hd2
    -> ( Dist is max(Dist,J1-I1), J1 is J+1 ),
       computedistance([Hd1|Tl1],Tl2,I1,J1,Dist)
    ;  Hd1 > Hd2
    -> ( Dist is max(Dist,J1-I1),I1 is I1+1 )
       computedistance(Tl1,[Hd2|Tl2],I1,J1 ,Dist).
```

Most common error I get is :

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Comment: A couple of helpful hints... *Arguments not sufficiently instantiated* means you're calling a predicate or using an operator that requires a bound variable, but you're using an unbound variable. In this case, if you perform `X is Exp`) then `Exp` must be completely bound with no variables. I also see you have an error: `I1 is I1 + 1` which will always fail or give this error. if `I1` is instantiated in this case, it will fail because the value in `I1` can never possibly be the same as the evaluation of the value + 1. You're recursive predicate is also missing a base case to end recursion.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and expected output so we can better understand what the intention is with this code?